# B2C Custom Content - Output claim value as hidden field

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Is there a way to output a claim as a hidden field (input type="hidden") so that it can be used inside [custom JavaScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-and-page-layout?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) inside AAD B2C?

Setting a default value on a "ReadOnly" [DisplayClaim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-and-page-layout?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) gets the value out to the page:

```xml
      <ClaimType Id="myClaim">
        <DisplayName>DEBUG: Never display this</DisplayName>        
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <UserInputType>Readonly</UserInputType>
      </ClaimType>
```

but then you have to goto extra lengths to hide it that may become fragile if the B2C HTML DOM output format ever changes:

```js
var myClaim = document.getElementById("myClaim"); //too bad this cant just be a hidden field
var myClaimValue = myClaim.value; 
myClaim.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = "none"; //hide parent div's parent li
```

Comment: Not out of the box, but it would be an interesting feature that I would vote for!

Comment: @BradC. i will take your comment to heart, one moment :)

Comment: @BradC. - upvotes :)  https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/42831765-b2c-custom-content-add-hiddenfield-as-userinputt

Comment: Great job - I've submitted my upvote!

Comment: If you explicitely use content version then the DOM should not change. Every custom UI template relies on DOM looking in a specific way. See docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/contentdefinitions#select-a-page-layout

Comment: @wojtekdo - good point, but it sill makes my client side code fragile to future template updates, whereas if there was a hidden field control i wouldnt need to write that code.

Answer (score 2):

As commented on initial question, this is not supported currently.

If you ended up on this post, please upvote this feature request: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/5f39dfe1-b625-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0789

Comment: That just shows you how much MSFT cares about user feedback

Comment: @JakubBochenski - updated with new link , microsoft recently back in december migrated old feedback without any way to track what you had previously followed

Comment: Just like I said, if they cared they would keep the old URLs with a redirect to new site

Comment: @JakubBochenski - i feel your pain :) ... https://felickz.github.io/dev/2022/02/09/MicrosoftUserVoice.html

Comment: that's useful - I tried googling the title but it seems the new pages are poorly ranked as i found nothing, so it seems searching the site directly should help